# Can I delete my mayor and replace them with my second character?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I really don't want my mayor(Roxy) anymore and I love my second chara(Piper) so can I delete her and have Piper be mayor??

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Whoever starts the game will always be the Mayor of their town. The two options I ***could*** suggest are:

1. Try deleting the character who is mayor of the town.
2. Start over from scratch.

I am in no way, however, advising you to perform either of the two actions above as these both provide negative outcomes to your saved game.